# ¿Por que v-model no actualiza la variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Con el siguiente código logro hacer que `request.limits` se actualice con el `input text`, sin embargo cuando hago la petición `$.http`, se envía el valor que había asignado por defecto.

¿Cómo envío la `request.limits` actualizado con el valor del `input`?

**JS**

```
var dataResponse = new Vue({
      el: '#govue',
      data: {
       productos : [
                             { 
                                sku: '0' ,
                                model: '0' ,
                                description: '0' ,
                                color: '0' ,
                                price: '0' ,
                                saleprice: '0' ,
                             }
                        ],
        request : [
                        {
                            limits: "0-0",
                            portal: "none"
                        }
                     ],
        feed: "none",
        bolData: false,
        status: "none"
        },

      methods:{

         createProduct: function(){

                this.status ="loading data...";
                this.bol=true;

                this.$forceUpdate();
             this.$http.post('newSiaScrap.php',{ data: this.request }).then(function (response) {
                  // success callback
            this.ajax=response.body;
                console.log("resp:"+response);
                this.bol=false;
                this.carga = "loaded!";
              }, function (response) {

                alert("error");
              });
             return false;
         }
      }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="govue">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <hr><br>
    <h1>Creaciones automáticas </h1>
    <code>AgmDeveloper Powah! pls.. update DB</code>
    <hr>
    <code>
        UPDATE PRODUCT_SCRAP_INV set Band_Tone='Dorado' WHERE Band_Tone='oro' <br>
        UPDATE PRODUCT_SCRAP_INV set Band_Tone='Plateado' WHERE Band_Tone='acero'<br>
        UPDATE PRODUCT_SCRAP_INV set Water_Resistant=Water_Resistant+'ts' WHERE Water_Resistant like '%m' <br>
        PANAMA REQUIRED  DELETE PRODUCT WEIGHT<br>
    </code>


    <label for="portal">PORTAL:</label>
        <select name="portal" id="portal" class="form-control">
            <option value="ECUADOR">ECUADOR</option>
            <option value="PANAMA">PANAMA</option>

        </select>

        <label for="limit">Rango de búsqueda en OTB:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="request.limits" name="limits" id="limit" placeholder="from-to  [0-800]" class="form-control">
        <hr>
        <input type="button" value="Run Forest Run"  v-on:click="createProduct" class="btn">

    <h1> {{ request.limits }}</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <table v-if="bolData" class="table table-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="dataTh">
                    <th>Sku</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>PrecioOferta</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="data">

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe a que has definido `request` como un arreglo con un objeto dentro, pero al hacer el `bind`, lo haces, como si `request` fuera un objeto con la propiedad `limits` (`eg: v-model="request.limits"`)

### Solución:

Podrías definir a `request` como un objeto:

```
request: {
  limits: "0-0",
  portal: "none"
},
```

### Demo:

```js
var dataResponse = new Vue({
  el: '#govue',
  data: {
    productos: [{
      sku: '0',
      model: '0',
      description: '0',
      color: '0',
      price: '0',
      saleprice: '0',
    }],
    request: {
      limits: "0-0",
      portal: "none"
    },
    feed: "none",
    bolData: false,
    status: "none"
  },

  methods: {

    createProduct: function() {

      this.status = "loading data...";
      this.bol = true;

      this.$forceUpdate();
      console.log(this.request);
      this.$http.post('newSiaScrap.php', {
        data: this.request
      }).then(function(response) {
        // success callback
        this.ajax = response.body;
        console.log("resp:" + response);
        this.bol = false;
        this.carga = "loaded!";
      }, function(response) {

        alert("error");
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.5"></script>
<div id="govue">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <hr><br>
    <h1>Creaciones automáticas </h1>
    <code>AgmDeveloper Powah! pls.. update DB</code>
    <hr>
    <code>
        UPDATE PRODUCT_SCRAP_INV set Band_Tone='Dorado' WHERE Band_Tone='oro' <br>
        UPDATE PRODUCT_SCRAP_INV set Band_Tone='Plateado' WHERE Band_Tone='acero'<br>
        UPDATE PRODUCT_SCRAP_INV set Water_Resistant=Water_Resistant+'ts' WHERE Water_Resistant like '%m' <br>
        PANAMA REQUIRED  DELETE PRODUCT WEIGHT<br>
    </code>


    <label for="portal">PORTAL:</label>
    <select name="portal" id="portal" class="form-control">
            <option value="ECUADOR">ECUADOR</option>
            <option value="PANAMA">PANAMA</option>

        </select>

    <label for="limit">Rango de búsqueda en OTB:</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="request.limits" name="limits" id="limit" placeholder="from-to  [0-800]" class="form-control">
    <hr>
    <input type="button" value="Run Forest Run" v-on:click="createProduct" class="btn">

    <h1> {{ request.limits }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <table v-if="bolData" class="table table-responsive">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="dataTh">
          <th>Sku</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Precio</th>
          <th>PrecioOferta</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="data">

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, en realidad me falta aprender mucho, crei que solo se podían mandar objetos, Mil gracias